# Brodal priority queue implementation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

Have someone ever implemented a [Brodal queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants)?

Is it worth implementing or has high running time constants like the Fibonacci Heap?

Comment: Why the hostility to this question?  It seems reasonable to me.

Comment: i know! but i don't know why, i expected that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/priority-queues/) is a Haskell implementation of Brodal–Okasaki, which is a purely functional variant of Brodal's original data structure with the same time bounds. Since Brodal–Okasaki claim that their structure can be derived by tweaking binomial queues, I expect that pairing heaps would be faster for most uses, though depending on your application, there may be even better structures.

Comment: thank you! i'll give it a try! i don't know how you managed to find it on the internet, because it was really impossible for me